# How to remove right padding in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell in the Interface Builder and have added a label in it. The label has 3 constraints: leading, trailing and top.
The bottom one is to a button, but I don't think it's relevant for the question.

The problem is that, even though the leading, trailing and top constraint have the same constant, there seems to be an inherent inset or padding in the leading part. This can be seen in this image:
[image]

How can I remove it? Or how can I at least replicate it for the top and trailing constraints?

Comment: Did you check your text field's `textAlignment` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Uncheck** Relative to margin for this leading constraint and then set constant of this constraint to 8

[image]